# Rails routing by anchor identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I'm looking for how to define a route under the anchor identifier ie:

```
match '/#/pages/home' => 'pages#home'
```

or

```
match '/#/posts/:id' => 'posts#get'
```

Comment: You cannot. The part of the url after # (anchor) cannot be passed to the server in that form.

Comment: That is correct, the anchor is client-side only and doesn't even get passed to the server.

Comment: Thanks through some of my own testing over the last half hour I've noticed this myself thanks.

Comment: @Dogbert and @elektronaut, see the following link <http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/?category=1303>. I don't know how this is working, but somehow it is. Although I don't really see the purpose of URLs like this, it would be neat to learn how they're implementing them :)

Answer (score 0):

# is a special character and you cannot really do that. But even if you could, why would you want to ?